# SQL server query for custom rank ordering

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this data set, and i want to fetch the data based on a particular status priority. Need help in forming the query. 
If the latest transaction for a order is approved, then i need to pick that one, else if it is not approved, pick the latest approved/validated one, based on which is the latest.
so out of the data below,

Small addition to the data. if the latest transaction of the order is canceled, should not fetch the data for the order id.

i need to fetch, transaction id 4, 6,11. how do i need to write this query? I am using SQL server 2008.

```
OrderId TransactionId   Status
1           1       saved
1           2       validated
1           3       amended
*1          4       approved*
2           5       Saved
*2          6       Validated*
2           7       Amended
3           9       saved
3           10      validated
*3          11      approved*
3           12      amended
4           13      saved
4           14      validated
4           15      approved
4           16      canceled
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
SELECT OrderId, TransactionId, Status
  FROM
(
  SELECT OrderId, TransactionId, Status,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY Status, TransactionId DESC) rnum
    FROM table1
   WHERE Status IN('approved', 'Validated')
) q
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

Output:

```
| ORDERID | TRANSACTIONID |    STATUS |
|---------|---------------|-----------|
|       1 |             4 |  approved |
|       2 |             6 | Validated |
|       3 |            11 |  approved |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/944406/3)** demo

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks much. could you please help me another bit. I forgot one scenario. can you relook at the data.